# Using UserID was a key in ASP.NET MVC (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, userid

I am doing a project, registration system and login in ASP.NET on C # for educational purposes.

I've already done everything, the whole system only works with one big problem:
When I create more than one account, I get the error that the primary key cannot be duplicated.
I am using UserID as PRIMARY KEY. I diagnosed the problem, I add UserID++ every time someone creates an account. But it still adds to the base value - 0. And every time I have a duplicated key (1). How to make an auxiliary variable that would store the number of people who created the account somewhere, and would not reset each time the program was started.
I want UserID to be added, not generated.
And is there an option to use a long long type as the primary key? Or just int?

I can attach screenshots that will be needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the database you're using ? generally the best way is to let the database generate the id part (auto-increment) for a row

Comment: @Orkad I am using database from Visual Studio. I want UserID to be added, not generated.

Comment: Visual Studio is simply displaying the database state. I suppose your database is sql server. You need to learn a bit how a database works combined with an ORM (entity framework i suppose). The web is full of examples for this

Comment: @Orkad
My question is how to make a variable that doesn't reset every time I fire the code?

Comment: Of course it's SQL database, but that's not the point

Comment: well use a "static" variable but its ugly